# Best way of dealing with products of different nature in symfony based marketplace

Tags: php, symfony

I am developing a marketplace functionnality with symfony2.

I might have products of very different nature : food ingredient or downloadable software. So weight is only relevant for the ingredient and download url only relevant for the software.

So far I have a product entity with every possible interesting fields which I select or not thanks to different child types of the main product type according to the context.

Is this the common way of proceeding?

I obviously don't want to create a new entity for every kind of product I could be using.
What could be a good solution ? An associated entity with attributes 'fields_nature' and 'field_value' ?

Comment: Common fields for products would be something like: units, unit of measure (u/m), location.  Food ingredients might have u/m = kg, software = each.  Location might be a separate entity if items can be found in more than one location.

Comment: yes, I have common fields. But what if I start to have about 50 non common fields/attribute types? Because I could actually have food ingredients, downloadable software, machinery equipement, sas plans, other products of a not yet defined nature...

Comment: The way I would do would be to use a configuration table connected to each product "type" and then use a many-to-many table that would contain the product_id, type_configuration_id and then the actual data for that product (value, createdAt, updatedAt, etc). That way you would be able to grow your product range with no real programming work providing you had a configuration page(s).